# Matlab imwrite - a filename must be supplied

Tags: matlab

I have an image in the directory:

```
C:\Users\me\folder\A1B1\A\0001.bmp
```

I have multiple directories `('A1B1\A', 'A1B1\B', 'A3B1\A', ...)`. After reading in that image and modifying it, I store the image under the variable `I`. I tried to save that modified image as `0001_1.bmp` using

```
a = 'C:\Users\me\folder'
b= 'A1B1'
c = 'A'
img = '0001.bmp'
sp=strsplit(img(1), '.');
full = fullfile(a, b, c);
scat=strcat(full, '\', sp(1), '_1.bmp');
imwrite(I,scat);
```

but I get

```
Error using imwrite>parse_inputs (line 523)
A filename must be supplied.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked the intermediate variables to make sure they're what you expect them to be?

Comment: yes I already did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code produces a cell (not a character array) containing the following file name:

```
C:\Users\me\folder\A1B1\A\0_1.bmp
```

which seems to diverge from the desired output:

```
C:\Users\me\folder\A1B1\A\0001_1.bmp
```

This should fix your problem:

```
a = 'C:\Users\me\folder';
b = 'A1B1';
c = 'A';
img = '0001.bmp';
sp = strrep(img, '.', '_1.');
full = fullfile(a,b,c,sp);
imwrite(I,full);
```